# WinRM Cannot find the computer using DNS name

Tags: powershell, winrm

We have a machine which has a DNS mapping.

When we try to do a new PS session using the mapped name, like this:

```
New-PSSession -ComputerName DNSMappedMachineName
```

Get this error:

`WinRM Error. Cannot find the computer. Verify that the computer exists on the network and that the name provided is spelled correctly.`

By the way, tried the fully qualified network name as well and still didn't work. And we flushed DNS cache too. Still same result.

However, if we do this:

New-PSSession -ComputerName ActualMachineName

It works fine.

Is there something specific that has to be done so that PS Windows automation can find the computer through its DNS name?

Comment: This is not a DNS issue, it's a [Kerberos/SPN mapping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ad/service-principal-names) issue. Map the new name to the computer account in AD with `setspn.exe -s HTTP/DNSMappedMachineName:5985 ActualMachineName` and your domain members will be able to authenticate the connection correctly

Comment: Thank you for the quick response.